# Slicing a List Returned by a Function in One Expression

Tags: perl, bash

I was playing with a solution for a question and I came up with this solution:

```
echo "hell-hello-helloo" | perl -e '@a=split(/\-/, <>);print join("-",@a[0,1]);'
```

It is just supposed to extract the first two tokens and remove the rest of the line.

My answer would have been cooler, more difficult to read and less maintainable if I could somehow move that first split inside the join and do it as one horrible piece of line noise.

I tried a few things, but I'm not sure how to do it.  What I am trying to get to is something like this:

```
echo "hell-hello-helloo" | perl -e 'print join("-",@{split(/\-/,<>)}[0,1]);'
```

Comment: subs and builtins return lists, not arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a perl oneliner

```
echo "hell-hello-helloo" | perl -F/-/ -ane 'print join("-",@F[0,1]);'
```

Or if you don't like the `-F` option to automate splitting, either of the below two:

```
echo "hell-hello-helloo" | perl -e 'print join "-", (split /-/, <>)[0,1]'
echo "hell-hello-helloo" | perl -pe '$_ = join "-", (split /-/)[0,1]'
```

Comment: That's pretty cool, but I'm kind of more interested in how I can execute that split in the same expression as the join.  (I think I have been writing too much ruby lately).

Comment: Aaaaahaaaaa!  Thankyou.  That's genius.  I just needed to lose the @

Answer (score 0):

You can do this very concisely using a regular expression

```
echo "hell-hello-helloo" | perl -ne "print /([^-]+-[^-]+)/"
```

Comment: Yes, thanks, but my question was really more about chaining a function that returns an array with an array slice.  I don't really care about the original problem. I just couldn't figure out the syntax.

Comment: Or echo "hell-hello-helloo"|perl -055 -E'say ~~<>,~~<>,"\b \b"'

Comment: (though `perl -nE'say/(.*?-.*?)-/'` is much shorter)